# Java - Graphics to image

Tags: java, image, graphics

Well I am a junior java programmer, in the last week I've been facing the following problem: I've got an image and a panel. Both image and panel are inside a ScrollPane, and they both need to move in the same time. When I try moving them together I get a flickering effect. Moving each of them alone though, works fine. I've read about double buffering and decided to implement it. My problem is that my image is very **very** big, therefore drawing it each time from scratch causes my app to get stuck. So instead I've been thinking of the following solution:

In my paint function, I'd advance the scrollbar of the large image(works fine), **draw a new image from my now updated graphics content** and draw upon it my panel's content.

Though as much as I looked for it on the web, I couldn't find an explanation of how to do it. So making it short, how do I use my current Graphic object to draw an image from it?

Comment: Why didn't you just update your original post? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392664/scroll-bar-problems-in-java-layered-panes/1393237#1393237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made an override from the paint method somewhere in your code.

You have to doublebuffer the frame:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.createBufferStrategy(2); // Two is the number of buffers
// Here is the order important: first set visible, then createStrategy
```

Then your paint-method in your frame: (Do not override a method)

```
public void updateGraphics()
{
     BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
     Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
     paint(g);
     g.dispose();
     bs.show();
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
     update(g);
}
```

This method you can use in a Thread:

```
new Thread("PainterThread")
{
     public void run()
     {
          while (true)
          {
               try
               {
                    updateGraphics();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
               } catch (Exception e) {}
          }
     }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you don't have to implement double buffering by hand. As far as i can remember here is a property (e.g setDoubleBuffered(true)) to activate double buffering.

with best regards

Comment: Any component that contains the components that are flickering.  The scrollpane, for example, or the Frame that contains it.

Comment: doubleBuffering is enabled by default - calling this won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a panel that extends some JComponent (like JPanel) and override its paint method. Something like this:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {


  @override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: well, i am doing it but since I have both the jpanel and the large image in scrollbars, when I try moving them their scrollbars together I get the flickering. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you construct the image elsewhere, (BufferedImage myImage in the example) _before_ calling g.drawImage, it won't flicker. I suspect you may currently be constructing your image within the paint method, perhaps successively calling Graphics object's different methods; it will flicker for sure.